# Black Image when loading the ID from a Mysql server

Tags: android, imageview

I have a MySQL database, which contains a list of people with its image ID´s. 
Like this: "0x7f020000".

These images are included in the APK. But when I add a person to the Database but do **not** update the APK, I want that there is some error message displayed. So how can I verify if the image is present and act appropriate?

Thank you

This worked, thanks user1364052 for the idea

```
try
{
    d0 = getResources().getDrawable(Integer.parseInt(ID.get(img0Zahl),16)); 
    d1 = getResources().getDrawable(Integer.parseInt(ID.get(img1Zahl),16));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    d0 = getResources().getDrawable(0x7f020197); 
    d1 = getResources().getDrawable(0x7f020197); 
}
```

Comment: When you say: "These images are included in the apk" and "but do not update the apk", what does it mean. Are you running with an old apk that is not having the images?

Comment: there's no such a thing as a MySQL in Android.

Comment: @user1364052 Then see my comments and my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to resolve this in code, it has nothing to do with mysql. Since the entry exists in your db but you don't have the image in your apk. Probably in the logic where you are retrieving the image by the retrieved id, you should verify if the image is present and act appropriate.

Instead of catching the NPE exception and you should display your error message.

Comment: sorry then my question wasn clear enough... "you should verify if the image is present and act appropriate." is what i want to know, do you have an idea how to do that?

Comment: @user1364052 You need to provide some code details, but probably when you are retrieving your drawable, like: `Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(id); ` you should check if the object is not null and display the proper message. Because you are saying that the image is blank probably you are doing some validation, but not displaying the needed message.